# Angular data loads after css , breaking design

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-services

I have a problem with my angular app with CSS loading. My app's CSS is getting loaded before fetching data from my server. Which leads my app breaking the design, any way to change the flow of it in a way that showing page only after obtaining the data from the server. Suggestions and solutions are welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your interpretation of the issue might be wrong : once CSS files are loaded, you can create an element with a class and the class will be applied. Instead of assuming where your issue comes from, could you post some code and/or make a [mcve] reprducing the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several options:

1) As already mentioned, you can use an `*ngIf` in your template to ensure the template details don't appear until the data is retrieved.

2) You can build a route resolver. A route resolver ensures that data is retrieved for a page *before* it initializes and displays that page. You can find out more about resolvers here: https://angular.io/guide/router#fetch-data-before-navigating

Answer (score 0):

use `*ngIf` in your template to make sure the template details don't appear until the data is retrieved.

You can try :

```
<div *ngIf="server_response_flag">
 HTML and CSS here
</div>
```

It will load complete html after your api response.